# Which is more suitable for mass encoding video Lambda or EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm helping with the Seattle Police body camera Youtube channel, see https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcdSPRNt1HmzkTL9aSDfKuA/videos?view=0&flow=grid&sort=p and http://www.today.com/video/today/57067068/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#57067068 The department wants to overredact and publish to Youtube each body camera video as soon as an officer uploads the video to the internal server. To do this SPD is going to use AWS. I want to find out if it's easier to use Lambda to process each video through FFMPEG or EC2 instances.

The process likely will be:
1. Officer uploads video to internal server
2. Internal script copies/uploads video to S3 bucket
3. Either lambda or EC2 gets video, overredacts it, uploads it to Youtube, and removes it from S3

The FFMPEG command I use is: ffmpeg -i [[input]] -threads 2 -crf 20 -preset ultrafast -vf format=gray,"boxblur=6:4:cr=2:ar=2"   -c:v libx264 -an [[output]]

Comment: You could also use the elastic transcoding service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 can work pretty well. You could use Ubuntu, install ffmpeg via apt-get and you're ready to roll. You'll have the advantage of easy storing to S3 as well